# how to set shadow of UItextview border?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextview

Hi i want to set shadow of UItextView like below in image.

[image]

I have tried below code but it does not give me same result rather it also make the text of UITextView as shadow.

```
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
self.tv_comments.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
self.tv_comments.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
self.tv_comments.textColor = UIColor.black
```

Above code results me this view which is not required

[image]

Comment: You could try wrapping the UITextView with UIView and set the shadow of UIView instead

Answer (score 3):

The below code works fine

```
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
self.tv_comments.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

However, when `masksToBounds = false`, any sublayers that extend outside the layer's boundaries will be visible. So `UITextField` scroll text outside the layer.

If this is a problem for you, just add another `UIView` under your `UITextView` and set it's layer to display shadow.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two issues:

1) Border

Your desired output does not have a border. So do not set one.

2) View clips shadow

By default a `UIView` clips its content to its `bounds`. As a result, you can not see anything drawn outside the bounds (your shadow). Set `clipsToBounds` to `false`.

Working example:

```
// Test view setup
let parent = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
parent.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
let tv_comments = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 50.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
tv_comments.text = "Test Test Test Test Test Test "
tv_comments.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
parent.addSubview(tv_comments)

// replace your code with the code below
tv_comments.clipsToBounds = false

tv_comments.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
tv_comments.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
tv_comments.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
tv_comments.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
tv_comments.textColor = UIColor.black
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have text view with constraints addded.

Comment: Does not matter. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Is your `UITextView` background color is **clear color** ? If yes, then set the background color of `UITextView` or `UITextView` layer background color. Because **setting UITextView background color nik will set it's layer's background color to nil**.So

```
self.tv_comments.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
//or self.tv_comments.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
//self.tv_comments.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

self.tv_comments.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
self.tv_comments.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
self.tv_comments.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
self.tv_comments.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
self.tv_comments.textColor = UIColor.black
```